# What is wrong with this Media Query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This media query doesn't seem to work. What is wrong with it? I have tried basic changes (like text color to red) to test if it works and it doesn't make any difference.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) { 

    .brand-heading {
        margin-left: 250px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .intro-text { 
        margin-left: 100px; 
        text-align: center;
    }

    .js-scroll-trigger {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. How are you testing?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're expecting, what you're getting and the difference between it? It's unclear what you've asking.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

max-width means this style is apply to less than or equal to 1200px If want to see changes try changing it to max width 500px or 400px

OR Change it to min-width which means greater than or equal to 1200px;